# Stopping jquery animation after hover

Tags: jquery

How do I stop the animations from queuing without totally breaking it... I've tried using .stop() as below but it just seems to stop the animation at really odd times then not start again.

```
$('.work_tile').hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().find('.white_bkd').stop().fadeIn('fast');
    $(this).stop().children('div.arrow').stop().animate({
        "left": "+=305px"
    }, "fast");
    $(this).stop().children('div.tile_header').stop().animate({
        "right": "+=200px"
    }, "fast");
}, function() {
    $(this).stop().find('.white_bkd').stop().fadeOut('fast');
    $(this).stop().children('div.arrow').stop().animate({
        "left": "-=305px"
    }, "fast");
    $(this).stop().children('div.tile_header').stop().animate({
        "right": "-=200px"
    }, "fast");

})​
```

Comment: website add is www.fifteenten.co.uk

Comment: the first stop methods are redundant.

Comment: Can you please specify on what element you applied hover binding. I dont't want to go through your HTML-Code and search for some element with class ``work_tile`...

Comment: [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) can take parameters to control whether the queue is cleared and if the animation jumps to the end. These are both `false` by default. You probably want something like `element.stop(true, false).animate(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code. Hope it will work.

```
$('.work_tile').hover(  
     function() {
     $(this).stop(true,false).find('.white_bkd').stop(true,true).fadeIn('fast');
     $(this).stop(true,false).children('div.arrow').stop(true,true).animate({"left": "+=305px"}, "fast");
     $(this).stop(true,false).children('div.tile_header').stop(true,true).animate({"right": "+=200px"}, "fast");

     },

     function() {$(this).stop(true,false).find('.white_bkd').stop(true,true).fadeOut('fast');     
     $(this).stop(true,false).children('div.arrow').stop(true,true).animate({"left": "-=305px"}, "fast");
     $(this).stop(true,false).children('div.tile_header').stop(true,true).animate({"right": "-=200px"}, "fast");

     })
```